# Why MARS (earth package) generates so many predictors?

Tags: r, spline, non-linear-regression

I am working on a MARS model using earth package in R. My dataset (`CE.Rda`) consists of one dependent variable (*`D9_RTO_avg`*) and 10 potential predictors (*`NDVI_l1`*, *`NDVI_f0`*, *`NDVI_f1`*, *`NDVI_f2`*, *`NDVI_f3`*, *`LST_l1`*, *`LST_f0`*, *`LST_f1`*, *`NDVI_f2`*,*`NDVI_f3`*). Next, I show you the head of my dataset

```
   D9_RTO_avg NDVI_l1 NDVI_f0 NDVI_f1 NDVI_f2 NDVI_f3 LST_l1 LST_f0 LST_f1 LST_f2 LST_f3
2   1.866667  0.3082  0.3290  0.4785  0.4330  0.5844  38.25  30.87     31  21.23  17.92
3   2.000000  0.2164  0.2119  0.2334  0.2539  0.4686   35.7   29.7  28.35  21.67  17.71
4   1.200000  0.2324  0.2503  0.2640  0.2697  0.4726  40.13   33.3  28.95  22.81  16.29
5   1.600000  0.1865  0.2070  0.2104  0.2164  0.3911  43.26  35.79  30.22  23.07  17.88
6   1.800000  0.2757  0.3123  0.3462  0.3778  0.5482  43.99  36.06  30.26  21.36  17.93
7   2.700000  0.2265  0.2654  0.3174  0.2741  0.3590  41.61   35.4  27.51  23.55  18.88_
```

After creating my earth model as follows

```
mymodel.mod <- earth(D9_RTO_avg ~ ., data=CE, nk=10)
```

I print the summary of the resulting model by typing

```
print(summary(mymodel.mod, digits=2, style="pmax"))
```

and I obtain the following output

```
D9_RTO_avg =
4.1
+   38 * LST_f128.68                        
+  6.3 * LST_f216.41                        
-  2.9 * pmax(0,        0.66 -     NDVI_l1) 
-  2.3 * pmax(0,     NDVI_f3 -        0.23) 

Selected 5 of 7 terms, and 4 of 13169 predictors
Termination condition: Reached nk 10
Importance: LST_f128.68, NDVI_l1, NDVI_f3, LST_f216.41, NDVI_f0-unused,   NDVI_f1-unused, NDVI_f2-unused, ...
Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 4 (additive model)
GCV 2    RSS 4046    GRSq 0.29    RSq 0.29
```

My question is why earth is identifying 13169 predictors when they are actually 10!? It seems that MARS is considering single observations of candidate predictors as predictors themselves. How can I avoid MARS from doing so?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the class of your LST_f variables? Seems they are either factor or characters and MARS did build dummies for values. You can guess that from the name of predictor entering the model: LST_f128.68 (dummy for value 28.68 of variable LST_f1)

Comment: Eric, you are terribly right. Somehow, in the process of creating my dataset from the original `.csv` files, R considered the values of the variable LST_f as factors instead of simply numeric values. I coerced them to numeric using the function `as.numeric()` and, now, everything works smoothly. Many thanks for your prompt response.